# Reload parent iframe from another iframe using same dialog and iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dialog

I have a dialog page and i use it through the entire project whenever it is called buttons are dynamically generated and iframe opens the page related with the module. My question is when I clicked to user list, it opens and i see the list of users in iframe however when i clicked to add user and open another dialog for adding more user and then saving it. it does not refresh the parent page or iframe on it. It is same dialog page and same iframe but content is different. It is working IE because i use window.showModalDialog however it is not working on Chrome.

Here is the code for opening dialog

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
        var result;
        if (msie > 0)  // If Internet Explorer
            result = OpenModalDialog(rootPath + "modules/document/dialogs/secureusers.aspx" + location.search, "width=600, height=500", true, true);
        else           // If another browser
            result = OpenWindow(rootPath + "modules/document/dialogs/secureusers.aspx" + location.search, "width=600, height=500");

        if(result == true) {
            SecurityCallback.Callback("");
        }
```

and here is the dialog page

```
    <body onload="OnDialogLoad()" class="DialogBody">
    <table class="table" >
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DialogHeader" Runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td class="DialogHeader">
                    <table class="table2">
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="img/dialog/logo.gif" border="0" alt="Logo" /></td>
                            <td width="100%">
                                <span id="DialogTitle"></span>
                                <span id="DialogCaption"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" height="100%" style="border-style: none;"><iframe id="CallbackFrameDialog" name="CallbackFrameDialog" src="<%= this.DialogType  %>" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></td>
        </tr>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DialogFooter" Runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td id="ButtonContainer" class="DialogFooter" align="middle" style="padding: 3px; padding-top: 3px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </table>      
</body>
```

[Please see the image for my question](http://y48i.imgup.net/question01de.png)